# HTML select truncates text on click (using Google Chrome)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple select element.

The options' length isn't known in advance, and depend on the user's input.

The code I'm currently using is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="325">
                    <select multiple="" size="10" style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:auto; width:320px;">
                        <option value="a1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
                        <option value="b1">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like the select element to have a fixed width, and then when long lines are entered the user should be able to scroll.

**The Problem**

Using the current code truncates the option's text when I select it (number of 'a's is equal to number of 'b's):

[image]

[image]

**Does anyone know how to fix the truncation when selecting an option?**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Pangloss I edited the question (last line). I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: What browsers have you tested in? Where is it not working? Can you post a fiddle or something where it is reproducible? The code you pasted is working for me so I think the problem is elsewhere or a different browser than I'm using.

Comment: I edited the question. I'm using Google chrome 43

Comment: Are you looking for [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/60v2ec9h/)?

Comment: @Pangloss I'd like to have a horizontal scroll bar, and not just an ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

The `option` tag inherits the parent `select` tag's width. This means that by defining the selects width as 325px, you are defining each of the option's width as 325px too. I have no idea why it only applies to the selected option, I'm looking into it.

You could create a wrapper element and apply the styling of the `select` tag to the `wrapper`. Like so:

```css
table{
  border:0;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.wrapper{
  overflow:auto; 
  width:320px;
  height: calc(18px * 3); /*Option height * (select size+1)*/
  vertical-align:top;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
select{
  border:0;
  height:calc(100% - 2px);
  overflow-y:visible;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <select multiple size="2">
            <option value="a1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
            <option value="b1">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Although as you can see, this hides the vertical scroll bar off screen so it's not a perfect fix.
I'll update my answer if I find another solution.

Also, you may have noticed I used the corresponding CSS properties instead of attributes for the table and td tags: this is more approved nowadays but your method was fine so no harm done if you revert it.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of select box. E.g.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="325">
                    <select multiple="" size="10" style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:auto; width:820px;">
                        <option value="a1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
                        <option value="b1">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know the width in advance.

Comment: Would this be useful to derive the width  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585014/jquery-get-pixel-width-of-option-in-a-select-list

Comment: I was hoping this could be done in chrome without the need of heavy machinery such as jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can hide select and create selectbox in div:

```js
$('.opt').on('click', function(e)
{
 var opt = $('#sel').find('option[value="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');
 if(opt.prop('selected') == true)
 {
  opt.prop('selected', false);
  $(this).removeClass('bg1');
 } 
 else
 {
  opt.prop('selected', 'selected');
  $(this).addClass('bg1');
 } 
});
```

```css
table{
  border:0;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
select {
 width:320px;
 overflow:auto;
}
.wrapper{
  overflow:auto; 
  width:320px;
  line-height:1.1em;
  height:7.65em;
}
.opt {
 white-space:pre;
 width:auto;
}
.bg1 {
 background-color:#99d
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <select id="sel" multiple size="7">
            <option value="a1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
            <option value="b1">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>            
            <option value="b2">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>            
            <option value="b3">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>            
            <option value="b4">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>            
            <option value="b5">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>            
            <option value="b6">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>            
            <option value="b7">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>            
            <option value="b8">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
            <option value="b9">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
            <option value="b10">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
          </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="opt" id="a1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>            
            <div class="opt" id="b1">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>            
            <div class="opt" id="b2">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>            
            <div class="opt" id="b3">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>            
            <div class="opt" id="b4">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>            
            <div class="opt" id="b5">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>            
            <div class="opt" id="b6">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>            
            <div class="opt" id="b7">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
            <div class="opt" id="b8">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
            <div class="opt" id="b9">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
            <div class="opt" id="b10">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I added the following style to each option tag to avoid the truncate.

```
width: fit-content;
```